# Is `Account` a reserved word in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm stumped.  The following TypeScript code fails to compile with this error:

```
fails.ts(10,7): error TS2420: Class 'Account' incorrectly implements interface 'IAccount'.
  Property 'name' is optional in type 'Account' but required in type 'IAccount'.
fails.ts(11,3): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'id' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.
fails.ts(11,3): error TS2687: All declarations of 'id' must have identical modifiers.
fails.ts(14,3): error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
```

But if I **rename** `class Account` to `class Hello` it doesn't fail.  Am I going crazy?  Does anyone else see the same behavior?

```
interface IObject {
  id: number;
  table_name: string;
};

interface IAccount extends IObject {
  user_id: number;
  name: string;
};
class Account implements IAccount {
  id: number;
  table_name: string = 'account';
  user_id: number;
  name: string;
};
```

I'm using TypeScript ^2.3.4

Here's a complete example with failing and non-failing code: https://gist.github.com/iffy/9d518d78d6ead2fe1fbc9b0a4ba1a31d

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name `Account` is not a reserved word but it is [defined as part of `lib.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b162097c3c7f5e5174eb70124de8888669775dbd/lib/lib.d.ts#L4295):

```
/////////////////////////////
/// IE DOM APIs
/////////////////////////////

interface Account {
    rpDisplayName?: string;
    displayName?: string;
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    imageURL?: string;
}
```

TypeScript performs [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) on your `Account` and the one in `lib.d.ts` and that causes the problem you get. If you turn your file into a module, your `Account` will be specific to your module and TypeScript will stop trying to combine it with the global one.

For instance, by adding `export {};` you can trivially turn your file into a module:

```
interface IObject {
  id: number;
  table_name: string;
};

interface IAccount extends IObject {
  user_id: number;
  name: string;
};
class Account implements IAccount {
  id: number;
  table_name: string = 'account';
  user_id: number;
  name: string;
};

export {};
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've been bitten by this before. In my case it was `Element` or `Node`.

Answer (score -1):

List of Typescript reserved words:

Reserved Words :

The following keywords are reserved and cannot be used as an Identifier:

```
break             case              catch                 class  
const             continue          debugger              default  
delete            do                else                  enum  
export            extends           false                 finally  
for               function          if                    import  
in                instanceof        new                   null  
return            super             switch                this  
throw             true              try                   typeof  
var               void              while                 with
```

The following keywords cannot be used as identifiers in strict mode code, but are otherwise not restricted:

```
implements            interface         let                  package  
private               protected         public               static  
yield
```

The following keywords cannot be used as user defined type names, but are otherwise not restricted:

```
any               boolean           number            string  
symbol
```

The following keywords have special meaning in certain contexts, but are valid identifiers:

```
abstract             as                    async                 await  
constructor          declare               from                  get  
is                   module                namespace             of  
require              set                   type
```