# Typescript interface in interface rejected

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have the following two interfaces, I expected them to work but the error I receive is the following:

```
Type '{ locations: { "0": Location; "1": Location; "2": Location; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
  Types of property 'locations' are incompatible.
    Type '{ "0": Location; "1": Location; "2": Location; }' is not assignable to type 'Location[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type '{ "0": Location; "1": Location; "2": Location; }'
```

The sample code is:

```
interface Location {
  address: string,
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number
}

interface Route {
  locations: {
        [key: string]: Location
    }
}

var routeLocs: Location[] = [
      {address: "Test1", latitude: 46.491775, longitude: 8.906089},
      {address: "Test2", latitude: 46.610298, longitude: 9.256934},
      {address: "Test3", latitude: 46.618097, longitude: 9.264945}
    ]

var currentRoute: Route = {
      locations: {
        "0": routeLocs[0],
        "1": routeLocs[1],
        "2": routeLocs[2]
      }
    };
```

Example in Typescript tester here: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Location%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20address%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20latitude%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20longitude%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Route%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20locations%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Location%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20routeLocs%3A%20Location%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Baddress%3A%20%22Test1%22%2C%20latitude%3A%2046.491775%2C%20longitude%3A%208.906089%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Baddress%3A%20%22Test2%22%2C%20latitude%3A%2046.610298%2C%20longitude%3A%209.256934%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Baddress%3A%20%22Test3%22%2C%20latitude%3A%2046.618097%2C%20longitude%3A%209.264945%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20currentRoute%3A%20Route%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20locations%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%220%22%3A%20routeLocs%5B0%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221%22%3A%20routeLocs%5B1%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%3A%20routeLocs%5B2%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B)

Angular 4 code to clarify:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { Building } from './building.interface';
import { Route } from './route.interface';

@Injectable()
export class RouteService {
  routeChanged = new Subject<Building[]>();

  routeLocs: Building[];
  currentRoute: Route;

  constructor() { 
    this.routeLocs = [
      {address: 'Test 1', latitude: 46.491775, longitude: 8.906089},
      {address: 'Test 2', latitude: 46.610298, longitude: 9.256934},
      {address: 'Test 3', latitude: 46.618097, longitude: 9.264945}
    ];

    this.currentRoute = {
      "locations": {
        "a0": this.routeLocs[0],
        "a1": this.routeLocs[1],
        "a2": this.routeLocs[2]
      },
      travelTime: 240,
      travelDistance: 155
    };
    console.log(this.currentRoute);
  }
}
```

That leads to the following error:

```
Type '{ "locations": { "a0": Building; "a1": Building; "a2": Building; }; travelTime: number; travelDis...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'travelTime' does not exist in type 'Route'.
```

`route.interface.ts`:

```
import { Building } from './building.interface';

export interface Route {
  locations: {
    [key: string]: Building
  },
  travelTime: number,
  travelDistance: number,
  startTime?: string,
  endTime?: string
}
```

Comment: That's because [Location](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L11555) is an existing type. You'll need to rename your interface or put it in a namespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is \`Account\` a reserved word in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572982/is-account-a-reserved-word-in-typescript)

Comment: On the other question the OP was having trouble with `Account` but the basic problem and its solutions are the same whether the clash is with `Account`, `Location`, `Node`, `Element` or anything else.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem but it might be found elsewhere.

Comment: I recompiled it and it worked. Weird error and might be related to something else. But `Location` alone did not cause the error because I renamed and checked it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

`Location` is already defined within typescript's `lib.ts` as an interface. What you are doing is effectively extending the already defined interface with your own properties. However, as your error alludes to, you are missing the other fields when you go to make an object.

If you switch from `interface` to `type` it will no longer try to extend the existing definition and explicitly warn you that you're trying to duplicate the type.

[image]

I'm afraid you'll probably have to rename the interface to something else.

[your playground example update to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20GeoLocation%20%7B%0D%0A%20address%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20latitude%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20longitude%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Route%20%7B%0D%0A%20locations%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20[key%3A%20string]%3A%20GeoLocation%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20routeLocs%3A%20GeoLocation[]%20%3D%20[%0D%0A%20%7Baddress%3A%20%22Test1%22%2C%20latitude%3A%2046.491775%2C%20longitude%3A%208.906089%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%7Baddress%3A%20%22Test2%22%2C%20latitude%3A%2046.610298%2C%20longitude%3A%209.256934%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%7Baddress%3A%20%22Test3%22%2C%20latitude%3A%2046.618097%2C%20longitude%3A%209.264945%7D%0D%0A%20]%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20currentRoute%3A%20Route%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20locations%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%220%22%3A%20routeLocs[0]%2C%0D%0A%20%221%22%3A%20routeLocs[1]%2C%0D%0A%20%222%22%3A%20routeLocs[2]%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22route%3A%20%22%2C%20currentRoute)%3B)

Comment: It used to work for everything but I never used it in another interface the way I've done now. I will try and see if it solves it and will accept then.

Comment: I'm writing in Angular and it still does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: You get the same error after renaming Location to something else?

Comment: Yes, I do. I will edit in the Angular code to show you what is going on.

Comment: Perhaps you're still using `Location` somewhere? I've added a link to your original example (with the rename) that works for me and prints out.

Comment: I get a different error message and I don't understand it. Thanks for the link. I will upvote but won't accept as I still get the same error, sorry.

Comment: After recompiling, it works again and I renamed everything to Location and it still works. So, I am not sure where the error was but it is now resolved. Might be npm related or whatever.